# What is the difference between the runtime linker (ld.so) and the prelink program?

Tags: linker

What is the difference between the runtime linker (`ld.so`) and  the `prelink` program?
I know the runtime linker (`ld.so`) loads all the dynamic libraries needed for a program but what is the benefit of `prelink`? Both are doing the same job, aren't they?

Answer (score 3):

This is largely covered by [the `prelink` manpage](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/prelink.8.html):

> `prelink` is a program that modifies ELF shared libraries and ELF
>          dynamically linked binaries in such a way that the time needed for
>          the dynamic linker to perform relocations at startup significantly
>          decreases.  Due to fewer relocations, the run-time memory consumption
>          decreases as well (especially the number of unshareable pages).  The
>          prelinking information is only used at startup time if none of the
>          dependent libraries have changed since prelinking; otherwise programs
>          are relocated normally.
>
> `prelink` first collects ELF binaries to be prelinked and all the ELF
>          shared libraries they depend on. Then it assigns a unique virtual
>          address space slot to each library and relinks the shared library to
>          that base address.  When the dynamic linker attempts to load such a
>          library, unless that virtual address space slot is already occupied,
>          it maps the library into the given slot.  After this is done,
>          `prelink`, with the help of dynamic linker, resolves all relocations in
>          the binary or library against its dependent libraries and stores the
>          relocations into the ELF object.  It also stores a list of all
>          dependent libraries together with their checksums into the binary or
>          library.  For binaries, it also computes a list of *conflicts*
>          (relocations that resolve differently in the binary's symbol search
>          scope than in the smaller search scope in which the dependent library
>          was resolved) and stores it into a special ELF section.
>
> At runtime, the dynamic linker first checks whether all dependent
>          libraries were successfully mapped into their designated address
>          space slots, and whether they have not changed since the prelinking
>          was done.  If all checks are successful, the dynamic linker just
>          replays the list of conflicts (which is usually significantly shorter
>          than total number of relocations) instead of relocating each library.

The main difference between `ld.so` and `prelink` is that the former runs every time a dynamically-linked binary is loaded. `prelink` tries to reduce the time and memory taken by `ld.so` at program startup by pre-computing the library relocations involved in dynamically linking a binary; it stores these relocations, along with the information necessary to determine whether they are still valid, in the binary, and `ld.so` can use that information to skip doing its own relocation (as long as the pre-linked relocations worked).

Using `prelink` does have a number of adverse consequences, in particular:

- it modifies binaries, which means they can no longer be compared to their “origin” (package etc.) to determine whether they have been tampered with;
- it results in fixed relocations, which greatly reduces the scope of address-space layout randomisation and thus reduces the system’s security (for any given pre-linked binary, as long as the linked libraries don’t change the relocations will stay the same, which is very useful to an attacker trying to exploit a gadget in one of the libraries).